# php not parsing date correctly

Tags: php, datetime

I need to convert 'Nov22' into a date object that is in the month of November. I am trying the following - but it only works with months with 31 days:

```
$novDateString = 'Nov22';
$decDateString = 'Dec22';

$novDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('My', $novDateString);
$decDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('My', $decDateString);

echo $novDate->format('m');
echo $decDate->format('m');

// output
12
12
```

As you can see, both Nov22 and Dec22 go to December. In fact, all months with less than 31 days go map to the month ahead of it. Is this a known issue or is there an easy way to solve?

Comment: It's a good thing you're trying this today, since it's one of the few days of the month that you would have this issue. The problem is that you're not specifying the day, so it's defaulting to today, the 31st. Since there is no November 31st, it becomes December 1st. Prepend a 1 to the string, then check for `jMy`

Comment: That is a very good point...remember you're asking it to produce a specific date, not just a month/year stamp.

Comment: Yup, even alternatives, like `DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime($novDateString))` parse this as `2023-11-22` (and `2023-12-22` for `$decDateString`), so it thinks `22` is the day, not the year.

Comment: You need the DateTime instance?

Comment: Ahhh, in a way I'm glad I caught it then. I can manually set the date to the 15th with no probblems so I'll do that. Post an answer and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not specifying a day, it's defaulting to today, which is the 31st:

```
$novDateString = 'Nov22';
$decDateString = 'Dec22';

$novDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('My', $novDateString);
// DateTime @1669926271 {#4573
//    date: 2022-12-01 15:24:31.0 America/New_York (-05:00),
//  }

$decDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('My', $decDateString);
//DateTime @1672518273 {#4578
//    date: 2022-12-31 15:24:33.0 America/New_York (-05:00),
//  }
```

November 31st doesn't exist, so the day becomes December 1st. You need to prepend a day before the string, and then pass in the correct format:

```
 $novDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('jMy', '1'.$novDateString);
//DateTime @1667331673 {#4576
//    date: 2022-11-01 15:41:13.0 America/New_York (-04:00),
//  }
```